problemas con de kaggle
Hola estoy atorrado en un problema de kaggle, en el piden identificar si un elemento de un array de strings tiene una palabra especifica, esta tiene dos argumentos (dados por el ejercicio propuesto) que son doc_list y keyword, que son los argumentos de la funcion. Ahora mi problema es que una vez hago el código este al final devuelve un array vacío. pero cuando coloco un print al terminar el ciclo y ver el resultado me da como resultado la respuesta. No entiendo si es un problema de lógica en el código o aventación.
este el codigo:
res=[]

for words in range(len(doc_list)):
    if(keyword.lower() in doc_list[words].strip('.,').lower().split()):
        res.append(words)
return res

al correr el codigo en jupyter notebook (creo que es el entorno usado para las pruebas) este me dice que el resultado de mi codigo es [] en lugar de la posición que beberia estar la palabra buscada. luego lo modifique y le agregue un print justo despues de agregar el res de la siguiente forma
res=[]

for words in range(len(doc_list)):
    if(keyword.lower() in doc_list[words].strip('.,').lower().split()):
        res.append(words)
        print(res)
return res

en ese caso el resultado fue [0] (para el print) y [] para el return

No está del todo claro la tarea, sería útil proporcionar los datos entrantes.

Pareciera que te piden hacer una función ... Simplemente copie tu código en una función:
def buscar(keyword, doc_list):
    res=[]

    for words in range(len(doc_list)):
        if(keyword.lower() in doc_list[words].strip('.,').lower().split()):
            res.append(words)
    return res

doc_list = "manzana pera naranja ciruela uva granada guinda cereza".split()
keyword = "uva"

print("Palabra  ;", keyword)
print("Lista    ;", doc_list)
print("Resultado:", buscar(keyword, doc_list))

produce
Palabra  ; uva
Lista    ; ['manzana', 'pera', 'naranja', 'ciruela', 'uva', 'granada', 'guinda', 'cereza']
Resultado: [4]

Process finished with exit code 0

Parece que te falta o sobra algo que no muestras. En todo caso tu código no tiene sentido:
Aquí iteras por índice sobre una lista
for words in range(len(doc_list)):

pero si quieres recorrerla, la forma pythonica es
for words in doc_list:

Ahora quieres comparar el keyword contra el elemento de la lista
if(keyword.lower() in doc_list[words].strip('.,').lower().split()):

bastaría con
if keyword.lower() == doc_list[words].lower():

Eso, suponiendo que cada elemento de la lista es una palabra (no un texto con varias palabras)
Versión corta
def buscar(keyword, doc_list):
    return keyword in doc_list

retorna True cuando la palabra está en la lista.

lo siento, olvide mencionarlo pero ya la pagina kaggel te da la función, pero tu debes completar el código de adentro de la función. también tiene una función que comprueba tu respuesta.
Este seria el codigo en jupyter notebook:
def word_search(doc_list, keyword):
res=[]
for words in range(len(doc_list)):
    if(keyword.lower() in doc_list[words].strip('.,').lower().split()):
        res.append(words)
        print(res)
return res

Check your answer
q2.check()

Si asumimos que es necesario obtener una lista de índices de ocurrencia de palabras
(sin distinción de mayúsculas y minúsculas),
usaría el módulo  re  y  funciones  filter() ,  enumerate() .
Código:
import re
from typing import List


def get_index(keyword: str, doc_list: List[str]) -> List[int]:
    return [
        y[0] for y in filter(lambda x: re.search(keyword,
                                                 x[1],
                                                 flags=re.IGNORECASE),
                             enumerate(doc_list)
                             )
        ]

doc_list = ['manzana', 'pera', 'uva', 'naranja', 'ciruela', 'Uva', 'Granada']

words = ('uva', 'granada', 'Señorita')

for word in words:
    print(f"keyword = '{word}'\n   Resultado:{get_index(word, doc_list)}\n")

output:
(.venv) PS C:\KWORK> & c:/KWORK/.venv/Scripts/python.exe c:/KWORK/esSo.py        
keyword = 'uva'
   Resultado:[2, 5]

keyword = 'granada'
   Resultado:[6]

keyword = 'Señorita'
   Resultado:[]
(.venv) PS C:\KWORK>

